# How to debug JavaScript APIs in Chrome dev tool?

Tags: javascript

I want to step into(e.g.F11) Object.create() and see what is happening internally. Is there any way to achieve this in Chrome Dev tools?

```
var o = {name: 'pat'};
var p = Object.create(o);
```

Comment: Open console and paste that code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.create is native code. You can't debug it as it's not written in javascript. Wedkit and firefox developers have coded it in C or C++

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this code.
Open Dev Tool in Chrome:

**Windows:** F12

**Mac:** ⌘ + Option + i

Edit your code and put the "debugger;" before.

```
debugger;
var o = {name: 'pat'};
var p = Object.create(o);
```

Navigate with F11